# Unchecked behaviour of 'Always Expand Selected Conversation' is not working as intended

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-client

I've enabled `Show as Conversations` view in my Outlook client for Windows so that the same thread messages (with the same subject line) are grouped together and shown in a triangular expand/collapse icon. Although I've unchecked *View* > *Conversation Settings* > *Always Expand Selected Conversation*, threaded messages always get expanded automatically whenever the focus is on those threads without having clicked the expand/collapse triangle icon, which shouldn't be the case. However I also noticed for a very few threaded messages in my inbox, it works as expected that is not expanded automatically (in the collapsed state) unless I either click the triangle icon using the mouse or use the right arrow key in the board to expand the collapsed thread.

I expect threaded conversations not to automatically expand unless I manually click the triangle icon to expand and see the messages within that thread after unchecking the `Always Expand Selected Conversation` option.

I doubt if this could possibly be a bug in the Outlook client. I expect the thread to be in the collapsed state unless I manually choose to expand. Hope someone could provide a solution or workaround on this.

**UPDATE:** *Not sure if the version of Outlook matters here. I'm running Outlook Version 2108 (Build 14326.20784 Click-to-Run).*

Answer (score 1):

Go to File > Options > Mail > Other, uncheck that "**Don't automatically expand conversations when using the keyboard to change messages.**"

[image]

If the issue continues,press **Win key + R** to open the Run command, type **outlook /cleanviews** and then press **Enter**.

(Note: This restores default views. All custom views you created are lost.)

If none of this helps, I’d like to recommend you test this issue in a new profile.

In Outlook, select **File > Account Settings > Manage Profiles
Choose Show Profiles > Add**.
In the Profile Name box, type a name for the profile, and then choose OK.
Hope this can help you!

Comment: 1/ Thanks for letting me know the existence of `Don't automatically expand conversations when using the keyboard to change messages` option buried in the Mail settings. I hope you mean to **check** this option in my scenario over here, and not uncheck. I tried it out by checking this option. It works only if I use the keyboard to navigate through the messages. But if I use the mouse to just put focus on the conversation thread, it still works the old way, that is conversation expands automatically.

Comment: 2/ However even when navigating using keyboard keys, I noticed that for some conversations, I have to press the right arrow twice to expand the thread. Not sure why the behavior is inconsistent in its design in Outlook.

Comment: 3/ I'm afraid that I can perform **outlook /cleanviews** now, since I've done some customization across multiple folders.

Comment: Not sure if the version of Outlook running matters over here. I updated the version that I'm running in the question.

Comment: Meantime I also verified this behavior in one of my friend's Outlook client and it seems to work in the same way similar to the problem I see in my Outlook. This makes me think if this could have been fixed or addressed in any of the next higher version updates. What version of Outlook client do you run, by the way?

Answer (score 0):

This is my version

[image]

What about repairing your Outlook? To do this, here are the steps:

1. In the search box on the taskbar, type control panel and select Control Panel from the results.
2. Select Programs > Programs and Features.
3. Right-click the program you want to fix and select Repair, or if that’s not available, select Change. Then follow the directions on the screen.

Hope this can help!